# Laptop heating problems when on sleep

Tags: suspend, power-management, overheating, gpu

It seems like my laptop seems to heats up whenever it goes to sleep as the fan is not running. I'm aware that some components are still running while on sleep, and I'm almost certain that my GPU is running while sleeping, which is causing a lot of battery loss. I was wondering if there's any way to make shut off the GPU whenever the computer goes to sleep. I'm almost certain that heating up shouldn't be the expected behavior because it doesn't heat up when I'm using Windows sleep.

Comment: Please add to your question the output of `inxi -SCG -! 31 -y 80`. Are you sure it went to sleep? Check the logs with `journalctl -p warning -xe`. Which process was consuming CPU before going to sleep? Check with `htop`.